# Why am I getting an an undefined method error when I try to add email confirmations in my Rails 4 app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, email-validation

I'm a newbie at Rails and I was hoping somebody could help me solve this little problem.  I keep on getting an `ActionView::Template::Error` which says `undefined method 'verify_email_users_url' for #<#<Class:0x68d5730>:0x6ac35c0>` when I try to implement email confirmations into my Rails 4 app.

This is the relevant code for the feature:

app/controllers/users_controller.rb

```
  def create
    @user = User.new(user_params)
    if @user.save
      UserMailer.registration_confirmation(@user).deliver
      redirect_to root_url, notice: "A confirmation email has been sent to your inbox"
    elsif signed_in?
      redirect_to root_url
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end

  def verify_email
    @user = User.find_by_email_token(params[:email_token])
    @user.email_confirmation_token = true
    @user.save
    redirect_to @user, notice: "Your email has been verified!"
  end
```

app/models/user.rb

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

before_create :create_email_token

  def User.new_remember_token
    SecureRandom.urlsafe_base64
  end

  def User.encrypt(token)
    Digest::SHA1.hexdigest(token.to_s)
  end

  private
    def create_email_token
      self.email_token = User.encrypt(User.new_remember_token)
    end
end
```

app/views/user_mailer/registration_confirmation.text.erb

```
To confirm your email, click the URL below.

<%= verify_email_users_url(email_token: @user.email_token) %>
```

config/routes.rb

```
SampleApp::Application.routes.draw do
  resources :users do
    member do
      get :following, :followers (this line refers to some other methods)
      get :verify_email
    end
  end
end
```

app/mailers/user_mailer.rb

```
class UserMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  default from: "money@example.com

  def registration_confirmation(user)
    @user = user
    mail to: @user.email, subject: "Please confirm your email"
  end
end
```

Here is the relevant test that is failing.  How do I get this test to pass?

spec/mailers/user_mailer_spec.rb

```
require "spec_helper"

describe UserMailer do
  let(:user) {FactoryGirl.create(:user, email_token: "fj4543")}
  let(:mail) {UserMailer.registration_confirmation(user)}

  it "should send an email confirming a user's email" do
    mail.subject.should eq("Please confirm your email")
    mail.to.should eq([user.email])
    mail.from.should eq(["money@example.com"])
    mail.body.encoded.should match(verify_email_users_path(email_token: user.email_token))
  end
end
```

If anyone could tell me where I'm going wrong that would be great.  If you need any more information to understand what is going on here, please do no hesitate to ask.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use collection:

```
  resources :users do
    member do
      get :following, :followers #(this line refers to some other methods)
    end
    collection do
      get :verify_email
    end
  end
```

Comment: Hey now, I'm getting this error after making the change you suggest:  expected "To confirm your email, click the URL below.\r\n\r\nhttp://localhost:3000/users/verify_email?email_token=9b5fe8f5e94b368e1f53778287144c1f7e95a7c
e\r\n\r\n" to match "/users/verify_email?email_token=9b5fe8f5e94b368e1f537782871
44c1f7e95a7ce"  What should I do to fix this?

Comment: add `config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { host: 'localhost:3000' }`

Comment: I already have that in both my test.rb and development.rb files

Comment: You need to fix tests then

Comment: Hey could you please look at the relevant test that is failing that i've added above and tell me where I am going wrong?  Thank you!

Comment: change `match` to `include`